# Over slow internet connection, AVPlayer delivers AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification before track has actually finished playing

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

My app plays streaming audio files from the internet via an AVPlayerQueue. If I set the network link conditioner to Edge, I see some weird / unexplained behavior. Sometimes a track will randomly stop playing, and I'll get an AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification notification. Whenever this problem occurs, it's usually preceded by a somewhat long (10-20 seconds) period of buffering. This makes me think that it's some sort of internal "give up" timer, because something was taking too long. If that were the case though, I would expect to receive 
AVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTimeNotification instead.

I am verifying that the notification is for the currently playing item, so it's not like I'm responding to the wrong notification. I also tried setting a break point in my method that handles the notification, and the stack trace just shows the call to post the notification. There are also 10 frames that are hidden where I can't see what's going on.

I'm hoping there's a logical answer to this, and not the awful workaround I imagine where if this notification is delivered I check if the track is actually finished and if it's not I ignore the notification and replay the track from where it left off.

Comment: Hey, how did you end up handling this? Thanks!